# The last entry of the datagrid is lost while using partial processing with primefaces

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

i have a problem about partial processing. (I use primefaces 3.4.1.) I have a dataGrid listing services and each row of the dataGrid has a commandButton, "remove service", to remove the service. 
I remove the specified service from my service list in my backing bean and update the datagrid while "remove service" button is clicked.

Also, i have two buttons in the form; 
First button, "add service", works to add new service; I add a new object to my service list in my backing bean and update the datagrid while "add service" is clicked. 
The second, "save", button works to save all services. When "save button" is clicked, service list is inserted to database.

Btw, i need form validation since there are mandatory fields in my service object. So, the form should be validated while "add service" and "save" are clicked. But, the form 
shouldn't be validated while "remove service" button is clicked. If i use 'process="@form"' for "remove service" button, everything is ok. I can remove the specified service 
from my service list in the backing bean and the datagrid is updated properly. But as u know, since all form is processed, all input components are validated. If i use 'process="@this"' or 'immediate="true"' for "remove service" button, i can not reach the last entry. I mean, i cannot reach the last service. I guess it hasn't been posted yet when i click the "remove service" button. 
So, what should i do? Is there any suggestion about this situation? Thanks in advance...

My code is as below;

```
<h:form id="formServicesTab">
        <h:panelGrid id="pnlSvcTab" columns="1" styleClass="valignTop" width="100%">
            <p:dataGrid id="dgServices" var="service"
                value="#{subMerchantOperations.subMerchantServices}"
                columns="1" width="100%" styleClass="valignTop"
                emptyMessage="#{messagebundle.submerc_grdlabel_no_service}" transient="true"
                rowIndexVar="index" >

                <p:toolbar>
                    <p:toolbarGroup align="left">
                        <p:commandButton id="btnRemoveSvc" onclick="loading.show();"
                            oncomplete="loading.hide();"
                            value="#{messagebundle.submerc_btn_delete_service}"                         
                            actionListener="#{subMerchantOperations.removeService}"                     
                            process="@form" update="@form">

                            <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{subMerchantOperations.serviceRowIndex}" value="#{index}" />
                        </p:commandButton>                      
                    </p:toolbarGroup>
                </p:toolbar>

                <h:panelGrid columns="3" styleClass="valignTop" width="100%" bgcolor="F0F0F0">
                    <p:panel style="background:#F0F0F0;">
                        <h:panelGrid id="pnlDgSvc" columns="1" width="100%" style="height:100%">
                            <h:outputText value="#{messagebundle.submerc_label_svc_shortName}" />
                            <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                                <p:inputText id="txtSvcName" value="#{service.serviceName}"
                                    required="true" transient="true"
                                    requiredMessage="#{messagebundle.submerc_validation_msg_required}"
                                    converter="UpperCaseConverter" />
                                <p:message for="txtSvcName" display="text" />
                            </h:panelGrid>

                            <h:outputText value="#{messagebundle.submerc_label_svc_website}" />
                            <p:inputText value="#{service.serviceUrl}" transient="true"/>                           
                        </h:panelGrid>
                    </p:panel>

                    <p:panel style="background:#F0F0F0;">
                        <h:panelGrid columns="1" width="100%">
                            ..........
                        </h:panelGrid>
                    </p:panel>

                    <p:panel style="background:#F0F0F0;">
                        <h:panelGrid id="pgSvcFiles" columns="1" width="100%">
                            ...........      
                        </h:panelGrid>
                    </p:panel>
                </h:panelGrid>
            </p:dataGrid>
        </h:panelGrid>
        <p:toolbar style="background:white">
            <p:toolbarGroup align="left">               
                <p:commandButton id="btnAddNewSvc"                  
                    value="#{messagebundle.submerc_btn_addSvc}"                  
                    actionListener="#{subMerchantOperations.addNewService}"
                    process="@form" update="@form" />

                <p:commandButton id="btnSaveSubM"                   
                    value="#{messagebundle.submerc_btn_sendApproval}"                   
                    action="#{subMerchantOperations.saveServices}" 
                    process="@form" update="@form" />
            </p:toolbarGroup>
        </p:toolbar>
    </h:form>

@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class SubMerchantOperations implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8556103952857187080L;  

    private List<Service> subMerchantServices = new ArrayList<Service>();
    private int serviceRowIndex;    

    // add new empty service to the service list
    public void addNewService() {
        try {
            Service svc = new Service();
            svc.setStartDate(new Date());
            getSubMerchantServices().add(svc);                      
        }
        catch(Exception ex) {
            if (logger.isEnabledFor(Level.ERROR)) {
                ...
            }           
        }       
    }

    // Remove the specified service using index parameter got from the datagrid
    public void removeService() {
        try {
            getSubMerchantServices().remove(serviceRowIndex);   
        }
        catch(Exception ex) {
            ... 
        }                               
    }

    // DB Operations
    public String saveSubMerchant() {       
        ...
    }

    public List<Service> getSubMerchantServices() {
        return subMerchantServices;
    }

    public void setSubMerchantServices(List<Service> subMerchantServices) {
        this.subMerchantServices = subMerchantServices;
    }
    public int getServiceRowIndex() {
        return serviceRowIndex;
    }

    public void setServiceRowIndex(int serviceRowIndex) {
        this.serviceRowIndex = serviceRowIndex;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea what that `transient` attribute is doing on your `<p:dataGrid>`. I have reviewed the latest published version of the Primefaces PDF documentation and this is not listed as a valid attribute.

If you are finding that Facelet-based component validation is causing your empty form to fire validation errors on submit of one of your buttons, you might consider creating a method in your backing bean which is called by your submit method, and validates the state of elements on the bean. This is a popular approach with Primefaces, because unlike `Seam` we are not provided with form-level validation.

However, do check [your understanding of immediate=true](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/01/jsf-and-immediate-attribute-command.html).

Alternatively you might consider annotating your POJO's properties with [JSR303](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=303) annotations.

Since you're using Collections, ensure that your Service POJO [overrides `equals` and `hashcode`](http://jtechies.blogspot.co.uk/2012/07/item-9-always-override-hashcode-when.html) to rule out that something screwy isn't going on with your collection and causing your problem.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer and advices. Actually, i used transient attribute for another validation issue. When the validation fails, even the form is refreshed the input components are continued to fire. I prevented that issue with transient attribute. Btw i Will check jsr 303 according to your response. Thanks again...